# SQLite problem selecting two columns as one

Tags: sqlite

Basic table with empname and empdpt.
In a Sql Server table, I can do `Select empname + ' ' + empdpt as expr1` no problem.
  Can't do the same using Sqlite!!
  When I try to combine two columns [with data], I get back a 0.
I've tried in sqliteman and sqliteadmin as well as Server Explorer in VS.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
SELECT ("test" || " " || "test2") AS expr1 ;
```

**Update**

If these are columns you can do something similar: SELECT (column1 || " " || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;

Comment: Select empname || " " || empdpt as expr1 works...thanks...Any idea why the basic a + b doesn't work in Sqlite?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Don't know any reason and haven't found any answer for this on http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/. However someone said that it is the same as in Oracle and PostgreSQL. Here are a couple other functions that might be interesting for you (Sqlite3):
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Answer (score 13):

```
Select empname || " " || empdpt as expr1
```

The sqllite concat is the same as PostGreSQL ( || ) and not MYSQL or MSSQL 'CONCAT'

Answer (score 7):

for those who are trying to use the (working) solution of @merkuru

> SELECT (column1 || " " || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;

in eclipse or another editor:

you have to cancel the " with \

something like:

> SELECT (column1 || \" \" || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;

that's works perfect

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me in the where clause:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE(first_name || last_name) LIKE comparison_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me. I had to add if statements to my query, do to some values equalling `NULL` as follows:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN table.column1 IS NULL THEN "" ELSE table.column1 END) || " " || (CASE WHEN table.column2 IS NULL THEN "" ELSE table.column2 END) as ColName 
from table
```

note: I might mention my case uses SQLite with Python but should be the same for all SQLite cases