# SQLite selecting two columns (with spaces) as one

Tags: sqlite, terminal

This is an extension of this question: [SQLite problem selecting two columns as one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003358/sqlite-problem-selecting-two-columns-as-one)

How would I combine the two columns if there is a space in the column name?

This works:

```
SELECT (column1 || " " || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

This does not:

```
SELECT (column 1 || " " || column 2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ("column 1" || ' ' || "column 2") AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

OR this

```
 SELECT ([column 1] || ' ' || [column 2]) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

OR this

```
 SELECT (`column 1` || ' ' || `column 2`) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

Per the [SQLIte documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), you use single quote for strings, and double for identifiers, but you have the other options for compatibility

- 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
- "keyword" A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
- [keyword] A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
- keyword` A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Comment: Ha ... I am tried that 10x. I just noticed that there was an extra space that I missed. Thanks.

Comment: I think another problem was I was trying to combine a column with Null in it. I learned how to do that properly here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993544/sqlite-selecting-two-columns-as-one-with-null