# SQLite selecting two columns as one with Null

Tags: sql, sqlite

How would I combine the two columns if there is a Null in one of them?

```
SELECT (column1 || " " || column2) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```

I would like output to be:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT (COALESCE(column1,'') || " " || COALESCE(column2, '')) AS expr1 FROM your_table;
```