# SQL query for User.first_name OR User.last_name OR both?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm programming a Rails app that allows a user to search for other users. Currently, a user can search first or last name, but not both.

I'm using:

```
@users = User.all.where("lower(first_name) LIKE :search OR lower(last_name) LIKE :search", search: "%#{parameter}%")
```

Given that the attributes are separate, how can I handle a search like "Harry Potter" with a space? I've looked around at ignoring spaces and then trying to separate the first and last, but they all seem quite complicated.

Comment: I just got it working, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try concatenating firstname and lastname with `||`:

```
User.where(
  "(LOWER(firstname) || ' ' || LOWER(lastname)) LIKE :search",
  search: '%HARRY potter%'
)
```

Comment: @PanKe No luck again. I tried `@users = User.all.where("(LOWER(first_name) OR ' ' OR LOWER(last_name)) LIKE :search", search: "%{parameter}%")`

Comment: @AustinBurke assume you are using mysql, the function is concat https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003358/sqlite-problem-selecting-two-columns-as-one 

It should apparently work. I'm not sure why it doesn't

Comment: yeah, should work. Did you check the SQL that rails generates?

Comment: What's the code you're using, what's the rails stacktrace or logs of the code, what's the whole error if any @AustinBurke?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `name` to `first_name` and `last_name` then

```rb
User.where(
  "lower(first_name) LIKE :first_name AND lower(last_name) LIKE :last_name", 
  first_name: "%#{first_name}%", last_name: "%#{last_name}%"
)
```

Comment: The issue is that I'm querying different tables with the search bar. Not all user searches need to be split into first_name and last_name, so I don't believe this would work.

Comment: your requirement is like this? if there is a space, search as a fullname, if not, search as first or last name

Comment: So there are Tournament Names, Clubs, and Users. Tournament names can really be anything (e.g. "The Best Team in the World" or "Best Team"). Similarly for clubs. I need to return all results. 

I've already managed to query the clubs and tournaments, since their names are just one string stored in a `name` attribute. The issue is with users having a `first_name` and `last_name` attribute in the Users table.